# How to use templatefile in terraform EC2 launch template user data?

Tags: terraform

I am setting up an EC2 launch template with a user data powershell script and would like to be able to use templatefile in the script itself.  I was able to do this with an auto scaling launch configuration because it accepts the user data as a string.  With EC2 launch templates it requires it to be a base64encoded string and it did not seem to accept this:

```
user_data = "${base64encode(<<EOF
  <powershell>
  $file_content = @"
  ${templatefile("myfile.txt", var.myfilevars)}
  "@
  </powershell>
EOF"
)}"
```

Is there a variation of the above that would work?  Or another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may have an extra double quote `"`, specifically the one right after your `EOF`.

Try this:

```
user_data = "${base64encode(<<EOF
  <powershell>
  $file_content = @"
  ${templatefile("myfile.txt", var.myfilevars)}
  "@
  </powershell>
EOF
)}"
```